# CSHTML / Razor Querying SQL Without Foreach?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, razor, webmatrix

Is there any way to query SQL in a Razor / Webmatrix page to get a specific (distinct) record from a specified column in a single row without using foreach?

I know how to setup the connection and get data out using foreach but is there a way to get a single record from a specific column without a loop?

Issue I have is that I am not running a SELECT query. I am executing a stored procedure which does the SELECT within it. There is one column that has a specific identifier which is the same for all returned records based on the filter. I am trying to get just 1 instance of this value so that I can display it in my page header.

If I was using a SELECT statement I wouldn't have an issue. I would just get the distinct value from the column I need but with a stored procedure I can't specify columns, distinct, etc...I can only pass parameters.

Is there a way to get just one distinct value instead of all values from a column without select distinct?

Comment: Can you modify the sproc?

Comment: Yes, I can modify the procedure but what would I change? It works properly. The parameters work fine, web grid in the Razor page works fine its just that I also want to display a page title using a specific value in the result but can't. Because of the loop instead of getting the value to show up just 1 time in the header it shows up as many times as there are returned records.

Comment: Your view should never be causing database queries. This very clearly goes against the separation of MVC (model, view, controller). Do the count in the model, and pass it to the view as a number.

Comment: Example is, the proc accepts an employee ID and returns a bunch of info for that employee, lets say 100 rows. One of the columns is the full name and its the same for every row. I just want to show that in the header or title but just once instead of 100 times.

Comment: @arserbin3 I am not having issues getting the count. I need to get a distinct value from a specific column. Best practices aside, how would I do that if I am doing EXEC proc...and not SELECT FROM.

Comment: In your model add the EmployeeFullName property. And populate it once before you `return View(viewModel);`. That's the way to be doing MVC, and is far more maintainable.

Comment: Sorry, doing through phone and can answer fully in morning if someone doesn't tonite. But cast sproc result to a List, use `.First().FullName`

Comment: I got what I needed using `ElementAt()` now I can't figure out how to display a column that has a space in the name. I tried doing ["Column Name"] and just [Column Name] but that doesnt work. Any advise?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution to what I was trying to do which is to get a record out of a specific row and column. Used this:

```
var db = Database.Open("MyDb");
var sql = @"EXEC myProcedure";
var result = db.Query(sql);
var header_value = result.ElementAt(0);
.
.
.
@header_value.ColumnName
```